# mbed client for software update

Tags: arm, mbed

I think this is maybe a bit general question but I am having trouble understanding if mbed client is capable of doing what I think it does.

I have managed to buil and run correclty Mbed Client on a K64F board. I have connected it to the server and the API runs perfectly with I/O elements, led and button. If I am not mistaken the client it is supposed to be able to update software executed on the board (even Firmware?). I have been searching but I have not found how to do this. I find references quite confusing on this issues.

Is it posible to define a resource as a software pakcage that is uploaded (let's say with a PUT request) and the executed (with the POST request)?

Is it posible update the firmware itself?

Any reference or example where I can see how it works?

Is the M2MFirmware class related to this posibility?

Comment: which part of the board are you trying to update.  For normal mbed development the board shows up as a virtual drive, like plugging a thumb drive in.  you copy a .bin file over generally whatever you want to call it the debug microcontroller which is not the one you are programming, halts the mcu under test, takes the file you sent and shoves it into that mcus flash, then releases reset on that mcu.  that simple, just copy the file over.

Comment: Any sandbox or other development environment should just be a wrapper around that action.  you dont need a big fancy sandbox to develop for these devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a way, yes. LWM2M has firmware update resource specified. However, mbed Client can only do updates right now if you are connected to mbed Cloud - which is currently only available for partners - plus you'll need an OS which supports firmware updates... Just defining a resource is not enough as you need a bootloader capable of doing firmware updates too.

mbed Cloud + the updated client should be available to general public soon. Then the update capability will be available too.

Comment: For my understanding: when speaking about firmware update i think of the low level code, in this case the complete mbed client that will manage objects and it is separated from the upper functions/applications. Is it posible to disgregate this element from the functions to be executed? Can this aplication code be updated? Or the only objects actually supported by mbed client are input and output? Or is the firmware a monolitic element that contains every line of code to be run?

Comment: All compiled code is the firmware, which resides on flash. To update any part of the firmware you'll need an update client / update-aware bootloader. You could get around it by running an interpreted VM (like [JerryScript](https://developer.mbed.org/javascript-on-mbed/)) on the device - then you can just update the code as it is text - but then you open a completely new can of works. Better to wait for mbed Cloud to be opened up to the public.

Comment: Anxiously waiting. Is there any estimation of when it will be available?

Comment: Jan Jongboom, do you know if the new client is close to the release? Is there maybe a way to get a beta?

Comment: @amq, unfortunately I can't comment on this right now. Beta invites are only available for mbed partners at the moment.